# How to achieve the following result using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I want to extract telephone numbers as follows with the following regex:

```
/(?:(\+?\d{1,3}) )?(?:([\(]?\d+[\)]?)[ -])?(\d{1,5}[\- ]?\d{1,5})/
```

using these test cases:

```
"my number is 2435 6546 56756765" 
"my complete number is 55 40 60 5585"
```

I got:

2435 6546 56756

However I need the numbers, as follows:

```
2435654656756765
5540605585
```

So I would like to appreciate support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the given regex does not seem to fit in well with the given examples. The digits are separated by a space, contain at least 2 digits and are repeated 2 - 3 times.

What you might do is match that pattern and remove the whitespace characters after.

```js
const regex = /\d{2,}(?: \d{2,}){2,3}/g;

[
    "my number is 2435 6546 56756765",
    "my complete number is 55 40 60 5585"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex)[0].replace(/\s+/g, '')))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also replace directly all non digits

```js
 const str = "my number is 2435 6546 56756765";
 const num = str.replace(/\D/g, "");
 console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are taking spaces in your regex you should remove them when you get the result with `str.replace(/\s/g, '');`.

Comment: What about the letters?

Comment: In his code he gets "2435 6546 56756" so I assume that removing the spaces would do the trick.

Comment: He posted expected output:
2435654656756765

5540605585

Comment: If he wants to get in his case the 2 matches he should put the regex global flag.

Comment: No they are unique strings and they have to be returned as modified unique strings. That is done by wrapping the strings in an array and iterating over them.  The /g flag is needed so that not only the first instance of the pattern is matched and replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this.  Here's an old school loop - and a different, less efficiently written expression.

```js
var strs =["my number is 2435 6546 56756765",
"my complete number is 55 40 60 5585"]

for(let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++){
   console.log(strs[i].replace(/([a-z]{1,})?(\s)/g, ""))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = "my number is 2435 6546 56756765"; 
const num = str.replace(/[\D\s]*/g, ""); console.log(num);
```

It will replace the non digit letters and the space characters.